# What are the typical wood types used for Japanese traditional woodblock printing?

Tags: wood, printing

What are the typical wood types used for Japanese traditional woodblock printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Wikipedia's article on [Japanese woodblock printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodblock_printing_in_Japan):

> The text or image was first drawn onto thin washi(Japanese paper), then glued face-down onto a plank of close-grained wood, usually cherry.

Absolutely not suitable are open-grained species like oak or ash.